# Closing an async Response

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to close the current response but nothing happens when I try `HttpContext.Response.Body.Close()` and `Response.End()` does not exist.

The reason I'm trying to achieve this is because of legacy validator functions that write an error and close the response, or at least stopping the parent WebAPI method.

Example:

```
    private async Task Register_v2()
    {
        //Read JSON to object
        UserRegisterRequest userRegisterRequest = Request.ReadBody().FromJson<UserRegisterRequest>();

        //Validate object (legacy static method with a lot of logic)
        //Validate() should end the response if object not validated
        userRegisterRequest.Validate(isJson: true, isThrowHttpError: true);

        //Code still reaches here and request does not close
        string test = "hey I'm alive";
   }
```

Can I workaround this with middleware somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered throw in legacy code then catch in outer middleware?

Comment: Yes I have. The problem is I have other legacy methods that print out to Response stream and need to close the stream after they finish, without throwing an exception. So your proposed solution does work for errors which naturally throw an exception but does not work for non-exception messages.

Comment: I don't think you can, since the legacy code wants to manipulate the pipeline in all kinds of ways. Problem is that the classic ASP.NET pipeline doesn't exist anymore,as you've encountered. So _your legacy code isn't going to work with asp.net core_. You'll either have to upgrade the legacy code or downgrade to asp.net. Is there any chance that you can make some small changes to the legacy code? Like rewrite the Validate method to a function that returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to terminate the `Request pipeline`.

- Use `app.Run` in `Startup.Configure`
- Do not invoke `_next(context)` in `Middleware.InvokeAsync`

For your scenario, you could try second option by determining whether to invoke `_next(context)`.

```
public class FirstMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public FirstMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"This is { GetType().Name }");
        //decide whether to invoke line below based on your business logic
        //await _next(context);
        bool isValid = userRegisterRequest.Validate(isJson: true, isThrowHttpError: true); 
      //change userRegisterRequest.Validate to reutrn whether the model is valid
       if(!isValid)
       {
             await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Model is not valid");
       }
       else
       {
             await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't solve my problem, as I have many static validators which all accept different arguments in different methods. So, my trouble is closing the pipeline from inside of a static method.

Comment: Could you share us the complete code to reproduce your issue? I am not sure what is the static method and how will you invoke it.

Comment: Is `Register_v2` a web api method? It will return `Task` instead of `Task<T>`. What is your expected result from client side? You could try valide the `Request Body` in  the middleware. check my update.

Comment: Yes it is. The problem with your answer is that I have different objects, I can't write a middleware for each object such as `UserRegisterRequest`. Each WebAPI function handles a different scenario, this example is for `UserRegisterRequest` type objects, another example might be `UserRemovalRequest`. I can't find a way to communicate with the middleware and let it know it shouldn't go further to the next middleware OR to simply somehow close the current response.